# Views in the main window is invisible when build using Xcode 15.x Mac OS Sonoma

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode15, macos-sonoma

When we try to build mac application using latest Xcode 15.x and run in OS Sonoma the views in the main window are invisible and able to the new subview added to it.
The invisible view  accepting the user action and responding to the action.

1. The application working fine when we build using Xcode 14.1 on Ventura and Sonoma
2. The application working fine when we build using Xcode 15.x on Ventura and facing the issue in Sonoma

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Most probably /* Defaults to NO on macOS 14 and later. Defaults to YES on previous releases. Note some classes (like NSClipView) set their own default values differently than NSView itself.
 */
@property BOOL clipsToBounds API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.9));

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Well after a day of looking at the issue, I finally found that it was caused by a custom view I created that subclasses NSView. Because of the change that defaults Clip Bounds to off, it was drawing over the top of everything that was below it in the view hierarchy. Turning Clip Bounds on solved the issue.

Footnote: I had read all the advice & docs about the change in clipping & had tried to turning it on in my ViewController's View, forgetting that I had the NSView subclassed view as well. In the end, the only view I had to turn it on on, was that subclassed NSView.

---

I'm having the same issue & it appears that there is a bug in Xcode 15.2 IB. I don't know what it is yet, but I've discovered that if I drag one of the non-displaying views down to the bottom of the view hierarchy, it will now display when I compile & run the app. Also, adding a new view results in it displaying properly because it's automatically added at the bottom of the view hierarchy. I'm still trying to find the cause of the issue, but it seems that maybe the hierarchy or layout is somehow corrupted.